# Is it possible to get CPU alerts on Amazon LightSail servers?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lightsail

Is it possible to get CPU alerts on LightSail servers?

It seems like CloudWatch is not connected to LightSail, but I find it hard to believe there's no such option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use AWS LightSail with AWS CloudWatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645642/can-i-use-aws-lightsail-with-aws-cloudwatch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now.  Check out https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/02/amazon-lightsail-now-supports-resource-monitoring-alarming-and-notifications/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible to get CPU usage alert from lightsail server. [You may get good idea from this answere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645642/can-i-use-aws-lightsail-with-aws-cloudwatch)